# How do I destroy a Unity prefab when it goes off-screen?

Tags: unity, viewport, visibility-determination

I made an infinite path using `prefab.Path` moving in the negative x direction. I want to destroy the path clone once it goes offscreen.

My path move script is:

```
var Speed:float = 5;
var hasseen:boolean;
function Start () {
    rigidbody2D.velocity.x = -1 * Speed;
    hasseen=false;
}
function Update() {
    if(renderer.isVisible) {
        hasseen=true;
    }
    if(hasseen) {
        if(!renderer.isVisible) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

and my prefab script is this:

```
var path_pre:Transform;
var i:long = 0;
function Update() {
    if(i<1000000) {
        Instantiate(path_pre, Vector3(i*25, -3, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than polling `isVisible` many people use [OnBecameInvisible()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html)/[OnBecameVisible()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html).  Note however that they will report the object as visible if while it is drawn by *any* camera i.e. the Scene window counts.  As a result the game can behave differently in editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a game object with a box-collider which exactly covers your screen. Make the collider a trigger and attach a script to the object which implements the [OnTriggerExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html) method. The documentation article for OnTriggerExit has an example which covers exactly this use-case:

```
function OnTriggerExit(other) {
    // Destroy everything that leaves the trigger
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
}
```

This example destroys all game objects which leave the screen. When you want to limit this only to specific objects, make it check the `other`'s [name](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-name.html), [tag](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html) or check [if it has a specific component](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) to identify it as an object it is supposed to destroy.

Comment: i thought destroying path clone will save my RAM which will maintains the games speed,but game starts lagging after 3-4 mins very poorly...what is the reason for this?

Comment: @RajatSharma There are about a million possible reasons for this.